# Depth of Field algorithm implementation issue

Tags: depth-of-field

I am trying to implement the paper: [Real-Time Depth-of-Field Rendering Using Anisotropically Filtered Mipmap Interpolation](http://cg.skku.edu/pub/papers/2009-lee-tvcg-mintdof-cam.pdf) from Sungkil Lee, Gerard Jounghyun Kim and Seungmoon Choi.

Everything works fine till I reached chepter 5 (Smoothing forground Boundaries). After I created the DoN texture, on site 6 between (10) and (11) I don't know how to get value of `M` to continue. My texture has 1024x1024 pixels. The highest mipmap level I have is 10 (1x1 pixel). I don't think in the paper they talk about the maximum mipmap level (10).

Answer (score 1):

> If a DoN value is taken and magnified (using
> the circular filtering) at the highest mipmap level, M ,
> this value (i.e., ρ(M ); see Fig. 8c) can be used for finding
> the foreground objects and their boundaries that may
> occlude non-foreground areas.

I think this means that M is indeed the highest mipmap level.

Comment: Thats how I read it too.